# How to fetch n no of elements from a list in a loop.?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which may be of any length. I have a method which calculates results for 50 elements at a time. I want to use the list in that manner such that for every iteration i get the next 50 elements.

What is did is, with the length of the list i calculated the no of times my loop should iterate,

```
count = math.ceil(len(newList)/float(50))
```

how should i iterate such that i can get the next 50 elements every iteration?

```
for c in range(0,count):
    newList[:50]
```

how to get the next 50 and then next 50 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
for c in range(0,int(count)):
    print newList[c*50:(c+1)*50]
```

Comment: Simplest way!! Worked like a charm.